# Why my Vercel serverless functions not working in production?

Tags: serverless, vercel

Hello I have a problem when I deploy my application in vercel, I am creating a function without server that brings me the data of a collection in mongodb, using mongoose. In local everything works fine but when I deploy the function it gives me this error:

```
504: GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT
ID: gru1 :: 594vg-1620811347355-66f311d5c992
```

I understand that the free plan of vercel allows you to create functions with a maximum of 10 seconds of waiting, is this why I get the error? Or it may be for one of these reasons: https://vercel.com/support/articles/why-does-my-serverless-function-work-locally-but-not-when-deployed

**Serverless function:**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
module.exports = function(req, res) {
  const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
  const inmuebleSchema = new Schema({
    user_id: String, //{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
    desc: String,
    tipo_propiedad: { type: String, enum: ["casa", "quinta", "departamento"] },
    amb: Number,
    estado: { type: String, enum: ["venta", "alquiler"] },
    banios: Number,
    dorm: Number,
    coch: Number,
    direc: String,
    precio: String,
    images: { type: Array, default: [] },
    uploadedDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
  });
  const Inmueble = mongoose.model("inmueble", inmuebleSchema);
  mongoose
    .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
    .then(() => {
      Inmueble.find()
        .exec()
        .then(inmuebles => res.json({ inmuebles }))
        .catch(err => res.json({ status: "error" }));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was, I wasn't adding my site's IP to my cluster's whitelist.